# Can not upload file to vsftpd FTP server on CentOS running on Virtual Box

Tags: centos, ftp, webserver

so here is the situation.

i have already setup my FTP server on my CentOS on VirtualBox, i can successfully connect. to it using my HostOS FileZilla Client. but here is the problem, i can't upload any file directly to /opt/lampp/htdocs/ even though i have already change its ownership to the FTP username, and change the Folder permission to 777, still i can't copy, keeps on telling me, `553 Could not create file` error. and i am at a lost for any workarounds. some threads over the net cant give my definite answers.

Here are other information regarding my setup

Host OS - Win 7
 Guest OS (Vritual Box) - CentOS 6.4
    - Web server installed on Cent OS, 
      * LAMPP (proftp disabled since i used vsftpd)

By the way i am just using locally on my computer for testing environment.

Anyone can help me with this problem?

### **EDIT**

-rw-r--r--, l ftpuser ftpuser 20 Oct 15 18:19 test.php

test.php was uploaded to /home/ftpuser/

i can successfully upload there.. but how come i can't upload directly to htdocs?

Comment: basically i wanted to directly upload files to htdocs using ftp

Comment: Is it just this directory (`/opt/lampp/htdocs`) that has the issue? Can you successfully upload files other directories? If yes, include the output of `ls -l` on an uploaded file.

Comment: Do you login as a regular user or anonymously?

Comment: @ckhan.. yes unfortunately for lampp htdocs..

Comment: @pabouk.. hmm if u mean by regular user, by useing useradd? then yes, other wise i do not know how to login anonymously

Comment: @ckhan what do you mean i include ls -l on an uploaded file? i don't quite get it

Comment: OK upload a file, say `hello.txt` to a different directory, that is not the lampp htdocs. Then, log in to your server on console, or ssh -- get to a bash `$` prompt. Then type `ls -l hello.txt`. Paste the output of that command in your question above.

Comment: @ckhan please see my updates above